# Matlab intlinprog metrics differ, solver data identical

Tags: matlab

I'm seeing 2 disparate behaviours with when using Matlab's
[`intlinprog`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html)
optimizer.  As luck would have it, it involves large-ish data sets.
In 1 case, I do not set any of the [`intlinprog`
options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html#btv2x05),
going with their defaults.  In another case, I set:

```
MaxTime = 1e5; // Seconds of search time
MaxNodes = 1e7;
RelativeGapTolerance = 1.5e-2;
```

The `intlinprog` output from the non-default options is:

```
LP:                Optimal objective value is -357.115403.

Heuristics:        Found 3 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -335.773578.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Cut Generation:    Applied 32 cover cuts, 19 mir cuts,
                   and 1 Gomory cut.
                   Lower bound is -375.424457.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Heuristics:        Found 1 solution using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -343.770009.
                   Relative gap is 9.18%.

Heuristics:        Found 14 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -365.852376.
                   Relative gap is 2.61%.

Branch and Bound:
   nodes     total   num int        integer       relative
explored  time (s)  solution           fval        gap (%)
   10000     88.99        21  -3.688905e+02   1.733665e+00
   18380    123.86        22  -3.702995e+02   1.347593e+00
RelativeGapTolerance met.  Stopping.
```

The output from the default options is:

```
LP:                Optimal objective value is -357.115403.

Heuristics:        Found 3 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -335.773578.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Cut Generation:    Applied 32 cover cuts, 19 mir cuts,
                   and 1 Gomory cut.
                   Lower bound is -375.424457.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Heuristics:        Found 1 solution using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -343.770009.
                   Relative gap is 9.18%.

Heuristics:        Found 14 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -365.852376.
                   Relative gap is 2.61%.

Branch and Bound:

   nodes     total   num int        integer       relative
explored  time (s)  solution           fval        gap (%)
   10000     88.53        21  -3.685595e+02   1.824775e+00
   20000    127.96        21  -3.685595e+02   1.824775e+00

<...INTERRUPTED FROM SHELL COMMAND LINE...>
```

I manually stopped the execution because the default stopping
conditions would have yielded a long search time.

Everything is identical up to the "Branch and Bound" section, but then
the search is clearly not identical.  To rule out numerical noise as
the cause, I confirmed that all the `intlinprog` input arrays were
identical using `isequaln`.  In particular, arrays that do not exist
in one case also don't exist in the other, e.g., `Aeq`, `beq`.  The data for both cases was captured by saving the workspace just before calling `intlinprog`.

In a
similar manner, I ensured that the bevy of `intlinprog` options also
matched, other than the 3 above.  Unless there is a stochastic
component of `intlinprog` of which I am unaware, the search should be
identical.

What else can I check as the source of this discrepancy?

I am using Matlab 2019a.

**Evidence that problem is innate to `intlinprog`**

Here is a Test.m script that loads and shows features of the input
array data, and the diary output.  It clearly shows that that
branch-and-bound starts at a different point, depending on whether the
RelativeGapTolerance option is set.  The optimization problem in
question is is a binary program.

```
% Test.m
%-------
clear classes
clear java
load('ILPprobStruc.mat');
disp('ILPprob='); disp(ILPprob);

disp('Call intlinprog without setting RelativeGapTolerance.')
ILPprob.options = optimoptions( @intlinprog, 'MaxNodes',1e4 );
intlinprog(ILPprob);
   
clear classes
clear java
load('ILPprobStruc.mat');
disp('Call intlinprog with RelativeGapTolerance=1.5e-2.')
ILPprob.options = optimoptions( @intlinprog , ...
   'MaxNodes',1e4 , 'RelativeGapTolerance',1.5e-2 );
intlinprog(ILPprob);
```

Here is the output, showing the initial row of the branch-and-bound progress output for each case:

```
>> Test
ILPprob= f: [1642×1 double]
    intcon: [1×1642 double]
     bineq: [482×1 double]
        lb: [1×1642 double]
        ub: [1×1642 double]
    solver: "intlinprog"
     Aineq: [482×1642 double]
Call intlinprog without setting RelativeGapTolerance.
LP:                Optimal objective value is -357.115403.

Heuristics:        Found 3 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -335.773578.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Cut Generation:    Applied 32 cover cuts, 19 mir cuts,
                   and 1 Gomory cut.
                   Lower bound is -375.424457.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Heuristics:        Found 1 solution using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -343.770009.
                   Relative gap is 9.18%.

Heuristics:        Found 14 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -365.852376.
                   Relative gap is 2.61%.

Branch and Bound:

   nodes     total   num int        integer       relative
explored  time (s)  solution           fval        gap (%)
   10000     97.30        21  -3.685595e+02   1.824775e+00

Solver stopped prematurely. Integer feasible point found.

Intlinprog stopped because it reached the maximum number of nodes,
options.MaxNodes = 10000 (the selected value). The intcon
variables are integer within tolerance, options.IntegerTolerance =
1e-05 (the default value).

Call intlinprog with RelativeGapTolerance=1.5e-2.
LP:                Optimal objective value is -357.115403.

Heuristics:        Found 3 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -335.773578.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Cut Generation:    Applied 32 cover cuts, 19 mir cuts,
                   and 1 Gomory cut.
                   Lower bound is -375.424457.
                   Relative gap is 11.77%.

Heuristics:        Found 1 solution using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -343.770009.
                   Relative gap is 9.18%.

Heuristics:        Found 14 solutions using rounding.
                   Upper bound is -365.852376.
                   Relative gap is 2.61%.

Branch and Bound:

   nodes     total   num int        integer       relative
explored  time (s)  solution           fval        gap (%)
   10000     98.74        21  -3.688905e+02   1.733665e+00

Solver stopped prematurely. Integer feasible point found.

Intlinprog stopped because it reached the maximum number of nodes,
options.MaxNodes = 10000 (the selected value). The intcon
variables are integer within tolerance, options.IntegerTolerance =
1e-05 (the default value).
```

Comment: I assume that the source of the discrepancy is the difference of input options right?

Comment: That's what I don't know.  The stopping conditions shouldn't affect the start of the branch-and-bound, as far as I know.  Both cases come from the same Matlab code that calls `intlinprog`, but they are invoked from different callers.  That's why I got my Matlab code to save the workspace for each case, just before invoking `intlinprog`. I load both workspaces afterward to ensure that the data passed to `intlinprog` are identical, other than the 3 options described.

Answer (score 0):

The MathWorks has explained that RelativeGapTolerance does affect the search strategy.  So a different search path can be expected if one sets RelativeGapTolerance away from its default value.